# Image In Cell with UITextView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, swift3

How can I display an Image URl inside of a textView with restraints?

I need to display the image in the tableView cell By the user clicking a button. Similar to to iMessage.

I would like the user to upload an image have the image preview in a textview then display the image in the cell where my(below) shows.

```
cell.textviewMessageLabel.text = profileDataArray[indexPath.row].message
```

I am making a chat room and would like the image URl to display in the textView and the preview of the image displayed in the textField.

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {

        //Assign new Photo and call to updateProfileicture()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.userProfileImage.image = image
        updateProfilePicture()
    }

    func updateProfilePicture() {
        //Assign current user ID
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        //Create an access point for the Firebase Storage
        let storageItem = storage.child("profile_images").child(userID!)

        guard let image = userProfileImage.image else {return}

        if let newImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {

            //upload to Firebase
            storageItem.put(newImage, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                   print(error!)
                   return
                }

               storageItem.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                   if error != nil {
                       print(error!)
                       return
                   }
                    //Upload User profile URL & photo to Firebase Database
                   if let profilePhotoURL = url?.absoluteString {

                        //Call function to upload new profile image
                        updateUserProfileImage(profilePhotoURL: profilePhotoURL)
                        self.changeChatPhoto()
                        //changeChatPhoto(profilePhotoURL: profilePhotoURL)
                        //updateGeneralRoomPhoto(profilePhotoURL: profilePhotoURL) 
                    }
                 })
         })       
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = profileTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "profileCell") as! profileTableViewCell

        //Set username label to display username
        //let usernameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        cell.tableviewUsernameLabel.text = profileDataArray[indexPath.row].username

        //Set message label to display message
        cell.textviewMessageLabel.text = profileDataArray[indexPath.row].message

        //Set timeStampLabel to current time AGO
        cell.tableviewTimeStamp.text = profileDataArray[indexPath.row].timeStamp
        cell.tableviewTimeStamp.numberOfLines = 0

        //Disables cell highlight
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: can you add screenshot for this or can you tell me that what you want to do exact ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're referring to a UITextField or a UILabel. Do you mean you want a preview of the image to show in a text field before a user submits it as a message? Or do you want thumbnails of previously sent images to show up in a label in the UITableView?

Comment: I would like a user to pick an image and display the images they chose in the UITextField then when they hit send show that image in the tableview cell in the TextView

Comment: This question is really unclear. What are you trying to do? do you want to add a picture inside the tableView cell?

Comment: yes exactly but insert the picture through the textView text